# Change the background color of my theme widgets

Tags: widgets

On the Widget screen I would like widgets that I have created specifically for my theme to have a different background color, how can the be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your widgets will get an ID based on the class name you specify. 
You can then write a CSS selector based on those values. Say that you prefix your widget classes with 'foo_', then you can select them with:

```
div[id*="foo_"] {
    background-color: red;
}
```

To add that to the admin pages add something like this to your functions.php:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'custom_widget_css');

function custom_widget_css() {
    echo '<style>
        div[id*="foo_"] {
             background-color: red;
        }
  </style>';
}
```